# Is it fine to have same variable name as event name?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, dom-events

I am creating custom event. I wonder if I can have same name of the variable to which the event is assigned as the name of the event itself. I mean the following:

```js
var myEvent = new Event('myEvent', {"bubbles": false});


document.addEventListener("myEvent", function(){
  console.log("myEvent fired");
}, false);

document.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

Here `myEvent` is both the name of variable and name of event itself.

Comment: if you like it and is clear ..  why  not  ...  ..

Comment: Yeah, functionally this will work. Generally speaking though, you want to make sure your code is not ambiguous - especially in a language like javascript where scope is so important. Like @scaisEdge suggests - if it is clear, then no problem.

Comment: Why would you want to?? Why can't you set the variable to `myEventVar` and the event to `myEvent`? It is possible but confusing to read!

Comment: @scaisEdge I am afraid any unknown name collision issues.

Comment: @SankarshMakam If the reader gets confused, he might come to this stackoverflow post. lol :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once you avoid the  var name that host object  as  `self`, `this`, `top` (within a frame), `location`  (information about the page that is currently loaded)

You can adopt a naming convention where the event var associated  to an event had the same name  ..